# I need to understand a css selector

Tags: css

I need your help to understand a selector of css that I wuold like to use to hide an element.
At this url you can see the page http://www.bachecahotel.com/annunci/all_ads.html

Well I wuold like to hide "Tutte le offerte" the second one in orange.
DOing some test I succeded in that using this css:

```
.juloawrapper.adsmanager-list.adsmanager-list-table div > h3:first-child
  {
    display:none;
}
```

But  I dont understand why it doesn't effect other h3 also if they are child of divs

Thanks
Frank

Comment: You `:first-child` selector only does what it says it will do, which is effect only the first `h3` element. If you take that out, you should see it effects all `h3` tags withing the parent element.

Comment: `div > h3:first-child` is the part that will target "tutte le offerte" and not the rest of the h3's in that element. It's because the other h3's aren't a direct descendent (`>`) of a div. They are a child of divs, but they're wrapped in an `a`, so `div > h3` doesn't match.

Comment: Thanks Micheal
So others h3 are child of divs same "altre offerte" but couse they are wrapped in <a> they are not effected.
that is correct?